# Find and enter that directory?

Tags: bash

I want to do some task in every directory in current path so I tried

```
for DIRECTORY in `find . -type d -maxdepth 1`
do
    cd $DIRECTORY

    #DO STUFF

    cd ..
done
```

but I got a long error of no such file.

```
updateall.sh: line 5: cd: ./abc No such file or directory
```

Why ?  I tried cd ./abc and it was fine.

thanks

Comment: Also, don't do `cd ..` but rather `cd -`. Instead of taking you up a level, `cd -` takes you back to the previous directory, no matter where that was. Also, if you use `( cd $DIRECTORY; do-stuff; )` you don't need to use a final `cd` at all as the current directory gets restored when you return from the `( ... )`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Actually when I used ubuntu I always use pop/push $DIRECTORY in script.

Comment: I think you meant `pushd` and `popd` - and they don't work in `ksh` (or other non-bash shells) as far as I know. Those commands _are_ handy though - when I used to use `csh` I used them a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `-mindepth 1`. Otherwise you `cd ..` out from the original base directory in the first loop repetition and end up in its parent directory.

Easy to notice when you dry-run the `find` expression:

```
$ find . -type d -maxdepth 1
.
./abc
```

In the first loop, you `cd .`, which does nothing, and then `cd ..`, from which you're unable to enter all the other directories you found.

---

If it's no problem with spaces in directory names, you can always `find $PWD` instead of `find .` to use absolute paths, or store the original `$PWD` in a variable you can `cd` to (`$OLDPWD` and `cd -` likely won't work though), instead of `cd ..`.

Comment: wow stupid me. Answer is right there before my eyes and I still miss it. Thanks for the tip too.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using -execdir, if you're using gnu-find. It's similar to -exec, but will execute the command from the directory. (It might be an ad hoc script, if it would fill multiple lines for example.)

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -execdir dostuff ";"
```

Using

```
for DIRECTORY in `find ...`
```

is vulnerable to blanks and similar stuff in directory names.

Example:

```
mkdir "a a"
echo "123" > a 

for f in $(find . -mindepth 1 -type d); do echo "using $f"; ls -l $f ; done 
using ./a
-rw-r--r-- 1 stefan stefan 4 2012-01-13 08:15 ./a
using a
-rw-r--r-- 1 stefan stefan 4 2012-01-13 08:15 a
```